# adding a video to div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I`m trying to add a video to a div using javascript after link is clicked. this is some of my code!I am not sure if I am doing it right as I never used videos with javascript before:

```
                 var vid = document.createElement("source");
                     vid.src="youtube link";
                     vid.type="application/x-shock wave-flash";
                     vid.style.width = "330px";
                     vid.style.height = "200px";
                 var x = document.getElementById('bottom');
                     x.appendChild(vid);

                     <div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: It should be vid.style.width = "330" + px

Comment: Not sure if this was your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is a valid way of using a youtube video, as you don't get an actual video link. Youtube has publicly available embed links that look like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9kd-PoHWah8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You can use javascript to create this. [Live demo here (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/CVmTaK4XGm6EvQdwzbcc?p=preview)

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/9kd-PoHWah8';
iframe.width = '560';
iframe.height = '315';

var bottom = document.getElementById('bottom');
bottom.appendChild(iframe);
```

See [the iframe api docs here (click)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for further info and more advanced options: